# Retina - prevent double serving of images

Tags: javascript, html, css, retina

For retina purposes, how to prevent double serving of images?

This works but [is not supported](http://caniuse.com/#search=srcset) by microsoft browsers:

```
<img src="image.png" srcset="image@2x.png" />
```

We cannot use css as we don't know the size of the images*.

We tried this:

```
<img class="image display-1x"
     src="{{ instance.image.url }}"
/>
<img class="image display-2x"
     src="{{ instance.image.url }}"
     {% if instance.imageRetina.url %}srcset="{{ instance.imageRetina.url }} 2x"{% endif %}
/>
```

Where display-1x and display-2x are toggled via retina media queries, however we have the problem that both images are downloaded which takes longer.

Anyway to achieve retina support with these requirements:

- img tag
- download only one image
- support IE10+

Is javascript the only way?

*it is a CMS environment where content is uploaded and replaced.

Comment: I believe this can be achieved by using the <picture> tag with two different images sources. IE should just ignore <picture> and read the <img> tag inside it.

Comment: @BlinkingCahill Interesting, thought it seems not to support IE11
https://caniuse.com/#search=picture

Comment: Yes it isn't supported in IE11 but IE 11 will just ignore the <picture> element and read the <img> element inside the picture element. HTML5 tags like video, canvas, picture etc allow you to put fallback content inside - they were designed to gracefully degrade.